# Switching a load using a 2N2222 transistor with a Wemos d1

Tags: arduino, transistors, power, circuit-design

So I have this... device... that draws about 0.1~0.2 A and requires 3.6 V. In the below schematic it's represented as a speaker. I want to be able to toggle the power to this device with a Wemos D1 mini (sadly, represented below as an Arduino since I can't find a Wemos in [circuit-diagram.org](https://circuit-diagram.org)). All is powered by [an 18650 shield](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002105094364.html) that outputs both 5 V and 3.3 V. Since a Wemos D1 pin can only handle about ~12 mA I need to use a transistor to switch the required 0.1~0.2 A.

Here's what I've come up with:

[image: My plan]

My 'reasoning' is:

- I need a 4k7 resistor to limit the current from the datapin (D4). I see 4k7 everywhere so... I guess that'll do?
- I was planning on using a 2N2222 (but I [have others](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32951552521.html)) as my 'switch'. This should drop around 0.6 V, leaving 5 V - 0.6 V = 4.4 V? This is a bit on the high side I'm afraid.
- Using the 3.3 V is going to leave 2.7 V for the switched load, which is too low.

My main question is: What can I do to get close(r) to the desired 3.6 V without using a ton of components? Add a dropper diode or two? Second: will this work at all? Does my reasoning make any sense at all?

(The device/load is a gag-birthday card which plays music at a rather annoying volume; it comes with 3 LR1130 batteries, 3 x 1.2 V = 3.6 V and using my bench supply I measured it using about 100 ~ 200 mA - I just want to control when it plays. It still plays when I lower the voltage, all the way down to 1.8 V but then it's barely audible - below 3 V is not gonna cut it, I'm afraid).

Comment: Your battery symbols are upside down and so is your speaker and npn for normal usage.

Comment: @Passerby I'm a total n00b with circuit-diagram.org and couldn't find a way to rotate; it turns out that drawing up->down or down->up matters. But do we really need to be so pedantic for what is, in essence, just a way for me to convey my general idea? I'm not designing a mass-produced product here, I'm tinkering with electronics. As a software-engineer I know every little detail matters - professionally. For beginners? As long as I can understand the general gist of it I'm ok with whatever they come up with. I also don't see what is 'upside down' about the speaker or NPN?

Comment: @Passerby All/most NPN's I google look like this? Anyway, I was just trying to make a better diagram than I can make using paint/photoshop.

Comment: it's not that it's symbol is upside-down but it's placement, in the usage you want. See GT's answer for the proper usage.

Comment: and yes sometimes we do need to be pedantic. Upside down symbols are confusing and can be an error in the schematic or that you intend to connect it that way. Of you can't take constructive criticism then this is the wrong place to ask.

Comment: I changed the battery symbols. Sorry man. And I wasn't / am not aware of "upside down" load and npn for "normal usage". I just found a diagram somewhere and based mine off it. Until now I didn't even know it matters if the load is before/after a transistor and that it depends on it being an NPN/PNP. So please forgive me for not understanding "upside down for normal usage" and not finding it very constructive _because_ of that.

Comment: No need to apologize. It's all about getting to the right solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can on have your load on the emitter side when your base voltage is a max 3.3v from the wells.

Try this...

[image]

Comment: And those are two dropper diodes? Any specific kind? Thanks for taking time to answer this n00bs questions!

Comment: Also... why would it matter if the load is before the transistor or after? And, if I used a PNP instead of an NPN, would it _then_ have to be on the other side of the transistor? I'm so sorry, not a clue what I'm doing.

Comment: Any 1n400x diode would be fine here. 0.6 to 0.7V drop each. And yes where the load is matters. So npn on low side and speaker on high side.

Comment: Yes, use any general purpose diode that can handle the load of your noise-make

Comment: Yes, use any general purpose diode that can handle the load of your noise-maker.  Also, a PNP transistor confuses the issue a bit and won't be as simple as this circuit.  The problem with a PNP on the 5v side means it will always be on - because the base voltage will be (5- 3.3v) of the wemos and current will flow and the PNP would be on.  And the wemos cannot handle 5v in (I don't think - but if it can, then you'd need to set to "input" to turn off current flow and "output" to turn on current flow.).  Low side switching with an NPN is by far the most common way to do what you want.

Comment: @GTElectronics both batteries are backwards ... the schematic shows -3.3 V connected to the power supply pin

Comment: Nice catch - The schematic is copied from the OP, it was his (minor) mistake.  I am certain he will not physically connect the batteries backwards. If he plans to physically connect batteries backwards, they need more help than I can offer here.

Comment: Op has updated the battery symbols to be correct vis a vis direction.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an easy way, since the MCU has 3.3V outputs:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNEurX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 is your load

R2 is chosen so base current is Ic(max)/20
(forced \$\beta\$ of 20), and current < 12mA.

Q1 is a relatively beefy PNP transistor

Note that LOW = ON and HIGH = OFF.

Comment: Won't the voltage for R1 be too low? I thought the transistor would drop some, so R1 wouldn't get more than... 3V or so tops? Thanks for taking time to answer this n00bs questions!

Comment: The PNP is connected as a saturating switch not an emitter follower so it will get close to 3.3V.

Comment: I have no idea what you just said, but I'll look it up and read up on the subject(s). Thanks!

Comment: Refer to the saturation voltage curve on [this](http://media.nkcelectronics.com/datasheet/s8550.pdf) 8550 datasheet. At 150mA it's something like 60mV with Ic/Ib = 10.

Comment: The noisemaker needs 3.6v so the 3.3v of @SpehroPefhany schematic will not supply enough voltage when switched with the PNP using 3.3v as shown in the schematic.  If you try with a 3.6v power supply and use the PNP, the PNP will not be off completely when the base is connected to 3.3v of the Arduino (unless you set the pin to "input" state.

Comment: @GTElectronics I assume it is designed to work with a battery so a stable 3.2V under heavy load will be fine. Worth a try, IMHO. Actually, you should tweak your answer somewhat- it has grossly inadequate base drive and it might be a good idea to parallel the load with a 1K resistor to keep the module from seeing overvoltage if it goes to a sleep state after making the sound, as they tend to do.

Comment: If you get to assume, I do to.  I'll assume everything will be fine. And "grossly" is a laughable overstatement. The OP found the device in a greeting card so I'll also assume it is powered with some button batteries and it draws under 100mA. I'll also assume that you rely on rules-of-thumb instead of looking at the datasheet.  Look up the DC current gain at 10 to 100mA - I think the 4.7k base resistor will be fine.   I'll further assume that @RobIII will come back with more questions if it doesn't work.

Comment: @GTElectronics The actual 2N2222 datasheet shows quite amazingly bad minimum gain, and at quite a high Vce. That's why I don't specify it. Of course there's no way of telling what OP actually got in that assortment from China. Might be a lot better product than the spec.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany you can ask but I haven't seen a tin-can 2n2222 in a long time (especially not from China) so the op likely has a 2n2222A.  The 2N2222A has DC gain of 200+ .  Let's wait for the OP to have a problem and we can talk him through the next steps.  I assume you read the part that this is a one-time gag device for his friend, right?  Not a consumer product with a risk of a recall.